# Can't decode html entities in title

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, decode, html-entities

I am having trouble decoding entities in the title from this youtube video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p7NMsywVQhY

Here is my code:

```
$url = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p7NMsywVQhY';
$html = @file_get_contents($url);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);

$nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');
$title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

//decode the '&#x202a;' in the title
$title = html_entity_decode($title,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'); //does not seem to have any effect
//decode the utf data
$title = utf8_decode($title);
```

$title returns everything fine except returns question marks where `&#x202a;` is originally in the title.

Thanks.

Comment: &#202a; is "left-to-right embedding" in unicode, which isn't supposed to be a printable character.

Comment: ok then how can I remove these types of code from the string?

Comment: search and replace would probably be the best bet.

Comment: any regex to remove all? The one MatTheCat posted does not work

Comment: Well, that wouldn't, because there's no character that represents #2029. it's a unicode control-character. think of it as an equivalent of the lower 27 ascii characters - they have effects, but no visual representation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to force correct detection of the charset:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="UTF-8">' . $html);

$nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');
$title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

echo $title;
```

Comment: If the document is not UTF-8 will this screw up the encoding?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if PHP provides any function to do that, however you can use `preg_replace` like this:

```
$string = preg_replace('/&#x([0-9a-f]+);/ei', 'chr(hexdec("$1"))', $string);
```

Comment: This does not seem to do anything

Comment: Hmm when I apply this regex the question marks remain in the string